# Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Tags: flutter, dart

can you help me? I am facing a problem that I don't understand why.

```
FutureBuilder<List<Filmler>>(
                future: karisikFilmler(),
                builder: (context,snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                

    var filmler = snapshot.data;

                   return Row(
                      children: [
                        ListView.builder(
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: filmler!.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context,index) {
                            var film = filmler[index];
                            return SizedBox(
                              height: 100,
                              width: 200,
                              child: Image.asset("images/filmler/${film.film_resim_adi}"),
                            );
                          },
                        )

                      ],
                    );


                  }else{
                    return Center();
                  }
                })
```

I'm getting an error like this. I tried to size `listview.builder` with sizedbox and container, but it didn't work.

Comment: `future: karisikFilmler()` Don't build the future as the future: parameter in FutureBuilder. See the first few paragraphs of the FutureBuilder documentation, or see my video at https://youtu.be/sqE-J8YJnpg